# Mule ESB move file into Alfresco using CMIS connector

Tags: alfresco, mule, cmis

So, I'm using Mule to grab files dropped into a folder and I want to push those files into Alfresco via the CMIS connector. I have Alfresco up and running, but I keep getting an error in Mule when trying to move the file. Below is my flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:cmis="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cmis" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cmis http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cmis/current/mule-cmis.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
   <cmis:config name="CMIS" username="*****" password="*****" repositoryId="6ddd8d97-e591-4327-bdaf-3e7be8604273" baseUrl="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/cmis" 
   doc:name="CMIS"/>
   <flow name="createDocumentFlow" doc:name="createDocumentFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/administrator/Downloads/Output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
       <cmis:create-document-by-path filename="#[header:originalFilename]"  folderPath="/Sites" 
       mimeType="application/pdf" objectType="cmis:document" versioningState="NONE" config-ref="CMIS" doc:name="CMIS"/>
   </flow>
</mule>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you add the exception to your question?

Comment: We were actually getting an exception about not accepting Byte Arrays or File Streams, but we fixed it by doing an Object-to-ByteArray transformation (who knew).

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working just fine. Used Object-to-byte-array-transformer instead of the File-to-byte-array-transformer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:cmis="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cmis" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cmis http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cmis/current/mule-cmis.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd ">
   <cmis:config name="CMIS" username="*****" password="*****" repositoryId="6ddd8d97-e591-4327-bdaf-3e7be8604273" baseUrl="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/cmis" 
   doc:name="CMIS"/>
   <flow name="createDocumentFlow" doc:name="createDocumentFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/administrator/Downloads/Output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
       <object-to-byte-array-transformer mimeType="application/pdf" doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>        
       <cmis:create-document-by-path filename="#[header:originalFilename]"  folderPath="/OCR" 
       mimeType="application/pdf" objectType="cmis:document" versioningState="NONE" config-ref="CMIS" doc:name="CMIS"/>
   </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cmis sync [cmissync.com/](http://cmissync.com/)

It works fine for me  and it always sync with your system.
Available options : Versioning,checkout, checkin, edit aspect, metadata etc..